Python PyAudio always record in mono sound
Here is my code:
import pyaudio
import wave

class AudioRecorder:
    def __init__(self, chunk=1024, sample_format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=2, fs=44100, filename="output.wav"):
        self.chunk = chunk
        self.sample_format = sample_format
        self.channels = channels
        self.fs = fs
        self.filename = filename
        self.wave = None
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.frames = []
        self.stream = None

    def record(self):
        def record_callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
            # self.frames.append(in_data)
            self.wave.writeframes(in_data)
            return (None, pyaudio.paContinue)

        print(f'{self.p.get_default_input_device_info()}')            
        print('Start Recording...\n')

        # init wave file
        self.wave = wave.open(self.filename, 'wb')
        self.wave.setnchannels(self.channels)  # Stereo
        self.wave.setsampwidth(self.p.get_sample_size(self.sample_format))
        self.wave.setframerate(self.fs)

        self.stream = self.p.open(format=self.sample_format,
                            channels=self.channels,
                            rate=self.fs,
                            frames_per_buffer=self.chunk,
                            input=True,
                            stream_callback=record_callback)     

        self.stream.start_stream()   
    def stop(self):
        if self.stream is not None and self.stream.is_active():
            self.stream.stop_stream()
            self.stream.close()
            self.p.terminate()
            self.wave.close()
            print('Finished recording')
        else:
            print('Stream is not active')            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    recorder = AudioRecorder()
    while True:
        print('Press 1 to start recording')
        print('Press 2 to stop recording')
        choice = input('Enter your choice: ')
        if choice == '1':
            recorder.record()
            continue
        elif choice == '2':
            recorder.stop()
            break

Here is my device info:

{'index': 1, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'Scarlett 2i2 USB', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 2, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.01, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.0033385416666666667, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.1, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.005671875, 'defaultSampleRate': 192000.0}

It supports 2 channels and I set 2 channels when I start recording. But the result is always mono sound. Any idea? Thanks.

is it sounding mono or is actually mono channel? I do get stereo from your code

@jupiterbjy It sounds mono. I can only hear from left side of my speaker. The strange thing is it sounds stereo if I set the channel to 1.
